# Where could my LAMP server be caching?

Tags: php, apache, caching, ubuntu, lamp

I have a home web server with Ubuntu 12.04, Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.3.10. It's not online yet, I just connect to it via LAN from a Windows machine. I have none of the Apache caching modules and no php caching (unless there is some default one I'm unaware of).

#### I've made a change to the site, but always get the previous version when I visit through my browser. How can I fix this?

In more detail:

I have a form that is generated in php. An array is created in one script, this is included in the view php file and used to make the form, and that's included by another file. I made a change to the array, and it's not showing up in the form. I do not have this problem when the files are on my WAMP server.

So far I've tried:

- Ctrl F5 in chrome. I also used Firefox, which I've never used to visit that site.
- Checking that I actually changed the file. I have. I deleted the whole site and uploaded it again. I also check the contents of the .php file in vim via SSH. It's correct.
- Added `EnableSendfile Off` to the httpd.conf.
- Restart Apache, reboot the server.
- Cleared Ubuntu cached memory with `sync; sudo echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`.

I am officially out of ideas. Any others?

EDIT:
Part of array getting loaded:

`$newAirmenMenu = array(
            'New Ratings' => array(
                'New Student Pilots' => 'new_s',
                'Students Pilots who got their Private Airplane Single Engine Land' => 'new_s2pasel',`

The menu is made in a function that walks through the array. Start of html output is:

`<div id='New-Ratings' class='panel-collapse collapse'>
    <div class='panel-body'>
        <input type='checkbox' name='newairmen[]' value='new student pilots'> New Student Pilots<br />
        <input type='checkbox' name='newairmen[]' value='student to pasel'> Students Pilots who got their Private Airplane Single Engine Land<br />`

Which is the old info in the array.

Comment: Sounds like caching may not be the issue then. Try using `print_r()` on the array to verify the server is running the latest version of the code and go from there.

Comment: You're right, print_r showed the old array. How can php bring up the old contents of an array?

Comment: Can you post your code snippet which shows this behavior? Would help in debugging

Comment: I added some of the code, I'm not sure if it will help.

Comment: Is OPCache disabled in php.ini?

Comment: I have no entry for OPCache in php.ini and it doesn't show up in the php info page. It looks like an extension I don't have installed.

Comment: OPCache is not bundled with 5.3